Calico network communication restriction between namespaces
I'm not an expert in Calico; this is a one-time project, and we might not modify it in the future. We have several namespaces, and the goal is to restrict communication between them. However, pods within the same namespace should still be able to communicate with each other. We also have two specific namespaces, ns-velero and ns-zabbix, which need to be able to communicate with all pods across all namespaces.
I've written a GlobalNetworkPolicy for this, but after applying it, the pods within the same namespace cannot communicate with each other (except for pods in the ns-velero and ns-zabbix namespaces). I've labeled the namespaces with isolat-group == 'isolated' and used a namespaceSelector.
Whats the problem? what did I missed?

    apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: restrict-cross-namespace-communication
spec:
  selector: all()  # Apply to all pods across all namespaces
  types:
    - Ingress
    - Egress

  ingress:
    # Allow communication within each isolated namespace
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"  # Only allow pods within the same namespace
      destination:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"

    # Allow communication from any namespace to 'ns-velero' and 'ns-zabbix'
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name in {'ns-velero', 'ns-zabbix'}"

    # Allow communication from 'ns-velero' and 'ns-zabbix' to all namespaces
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name in {'ns-velero', 'ns-zabbix'}"

  egress:
    # Allow communication within each isolated namespace
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"  # Only allow pods within the same namespace
      destination:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"

    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name == 'ns-velero'"
      destination:
        nets:
        - "ip1"  
        - "ip2" 
        - "ip3"   
        
    # Allow 'ns-velero' and 'ns-zabbix' to communicate with all namespaces
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name in {'ns-velero', 'ns-zabbix'}"

    # Deny all other cross-namespace traffic
    - action: Deny




You don’t need nets in the egress rules if they don’t apply to specific IP ranges.

The policy you’ve defined restricts communication, but it doesn’t explicitly allow traffic within the same namespace, except for ns-velero and ns-zabbix. Calico policies are restrictive by default, so even pods within the same namespace are being restricted unless explicitly allowed.
Here's your updated global network policy yaml with comments on what each block is doing
apiVersion: crd.projectcalico.org/v1
kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: restrict-cross-namespace-communication
spec:
  selector: all()  # Apply to all pods across all namespaces
  types:
    - Ingress
    - Egress

  ingress:
    # Allow communication within each isolated namespace
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"  # Only allow pods within the same namespace
      destination:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"

    # Allow communication from any namespace to 'ns-velero' and 'ns-zabbix'
    - action: Allow
      destination:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name in {'ns-velero', 'ns-zabbix'}"

    # Allow communication from 'ns-velero' and 'ns-zabbix' to all namespaces
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name in {'ns-velero', 'ns-zabbix'}"

  egress:
    # Allow communication within each isolated namespace
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"  # Only allow pods within the same namespace
      destination:
        namespaceSelector: "isolat-group == 'isolated'"
        selector: "all()"

    # Allow 'ns-velero' and 'ns-zabbix' to communicate with all namespaces
    - action: Allow
      source:
        namespaceSelector: "kubernetes.io/metadata.name in {'ns-velero', 'ns-zabbix'}"

    # Deny all other cross-namespace traffic
    - action: Deny


Test it out now

this test will show the pod can communicate with itself (or respond to its own ping ).
Now do cross-namespace communication test (Expected to be Blocked)

The bad address error indicates that cross-namespace communication is blocked, which aligns with the Calico GlobalNetworkPolicy we set up to prevent pods in isolated namespaces (isolated-ns-1 and isolated-ns-2) from communicating with each other.
Therfore Calico GlobalNetworkPolicy is effectively enforcing the intended isolation between namespaces.
reference- https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/reference/resources/globalnetworkpolicy

Now the pods inside namespace can communicate with each other, but also they can communicate with the pods in other namespaces.

Can you share all the yamls and outputs? edit your question to update it there. Will look into it.
